# Compiling issue with Recursive Decent parser (c++)

Tags: c++, parsing, vim, recursion, genome

I am having compiling issues with my c++ program, it is a recursive decent parser, these are the rules:

```
slist :: = stmt slist | stmt
stmt ::= decl | assign | print
decl ::= INT ID SC | FLOAT ID SC
print ::= PRINT expr SC
assign ::= ID EQUAL expr SC
expr ::=term PLUS expr|term MINUS expr| term
term ::= factor STAR term|factor DIV term| factor MOD term| factor
factor ::= primary STARSTAR factor | primary
primary ::= INTCONST | FLOATCONST | ID |
LPAREN expr RPAREN
```

I am still relatively new to C++, so i am not sure if i screwed up on something or it is my compiler. I am using VIM on genome/ubuntu terminal environment, these are the errors i am getting when i go to compile, it looks like a missing include header file but i am 100% sure i have included the header file:

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "p3lexer.h"

// this is a list of node types
enum PTreeNodetype {
    SLIST,
    DECL,
    ASSIGN,
    PRINT,
    MATH,
    EQUAL, 
    TERM,
    MINUS,
    STAR,
    MOD,
    STARSTAR
};

// this is a parse tree node
class PTree {
    PTreeNodetype   type;
    PTree *left;
    PTree *right;
public:
    PTree(PTreeNodetype t, PTree *l=0, PTree *r=0) {
        type = t;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};


PTree *Slist();
PTree *Stmt();
PTree *Decl();
PTree *Print();
PTree *Assign();
PTree *Expr();
PTree *Term();
PTree *Factor();
PTree *Primary();

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2){
        if(!setLexFile(argv[1]))
            return 0;
    }
    else setLexStdin();


    Token *t;

    // this code just tests the lexer; you should comment it out later
    while( t = getToken() ) {
        cout << t->getType() << ":" << t->getValue() << endl;
        delete t;
    }

    // instead, this code!
    PTree *parse;

    parse = Slist();

    if( parse == 0 ) {
        cout << "Syntax error! " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // here... a successful parse means we have to look at the tree
}

// slist :: = stmt slist | stmt
PTree *
Slist() {
    TokenType tt = t->getType();
    //fix this!!
    if(tt != T_SLIST){
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;

    PTree *stmt = Stmt();
    if(!stmt){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
    }
    else{
        return new PTree(stmt, slist);
    }
}

// stmt ::= decl | assign | print
PTree *
Stmt() { 
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = tt->getType();

    if(tt != T_DECL && T_ASSIGN && T_PRINT){
        pusbbacktoken(t);
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;
    return new(DECL, PRINT, ASSIGN);
}

// decl ::= INT ID SC | FLOAT ID SC
PTree*
Decl(){
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = t->getType();

    if(tt != T_INT && tt != T_FLOAT){
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return 0;   
    }

    delete t;

    t = getToken();
    if(t->getToken() != T_ID){
        cout << "Syntax Error!" << endl;

        delete t;
        return 0;
    }

    string id = t->getValue();
    delete t;

    t = getToke();
    if(t->getType() != T_SC){
        cout << "syntax Error! " << endl;

        delete t;
        return 0;
    }
    return new PTree(DECL);
}

//print := PRINT expr SC
PTree*
Print(){
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = t->getType();

    if(tt != T_PRINT){
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;

    PTree *expr = Expr();
    if(!expr){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    t = getToken();
    if(t->getToken() != T_SC){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        delete t;
        return 0;
    }
    return new PTree(PRINT, expr);
}


// assign ::= ID EQUAL expr SC
PTree *
Assign() {
    Token *t = getToke();
    TokenType tt = t->getToken();
    if(tt != T_ID){
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return 0;
        //recheck this, something is missing from here
    }

    t = getToken();
    if(t->getType != T_ID && T_EQUAL){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
        delete t;
    }

    string id = t-> getValue();
    delete t;

    Ptree *expr = Expr();
    if(!expr){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    t = getToken();
    if(r->getToken() != T_SC){
        cout << "Syntrax error on line " << endl;
        delete t;
        return 0;
    }
    return new PTree(Assign, expr);
}


// expr ::= term PLUS expr | term MINUS expr | term
PTree *
Expr() {
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = t->getType();
    PTree *term  = Term();

    if(!term){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(t->getType != T_PLUS && t->getType() != T_MINUS)
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return *term;
    }
    else{
        return Term(l);
        return Expr(r);
    }

    PTree *expr = Term();
    if(!expr){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;

    }
    delete t;
    return new PTree(expr, term);
}


// term ::= factor STAR term | factor DIV term | factor MOD term | factor
PTree *
Term() {
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = t->getType();

    PTree *factor = Factor();

    if(!factor){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    t = getToken();
    if(t->getType() != T_STAR && t->getType() != T_DIV && t->getType != T_MOD){
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return *factor;
    }
    else{
        return Factor(l);
        return Expr(r);
    }

    PTree *term = Term();

    if (!term){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
    }
    delete t;

    PTree *factor = Factor();

    if(!factor){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    PTree *factor = Factor();
    if(!factor){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return new PTree(term);
}

// factor ::= primary STARSTAR factor | primary
PTree *
Factor(){
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = t->getType();

    PTree *primary = Primary();
    if(!primary){
        cout << "Syntac error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;

    t = getToken();
    if(t->getToke() != T_STARSTAR){
        cout << "Syntax error! " << endl;
    }
    else{
        return Primary(l);
        return Factor(r);
    }

    return new PTree(factor, primary);
}


// primary ::= INTCONST | FLOATCONST | ID | LPAREN expr RPAREN
PTree *
Primary(){
    Token *t = getToken();
    TokenType tt = t->getType();

    if(tt != T-INTCONST && T_FLOATCONST){
        pushbacktoken(t);
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;

    t = getToken();
    if(t->getType() != T_ID){
        cout << "Syntax Error on line " << endl;
        delete t;
        return 0;
    }
    string id = t->getValue();
    delete t;

    of(tt != T_LPAREN && T_RPAREN){
        pusbbacktoken(t);
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;

    PTree *expr = Expr();
    if(!expr){
        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    delete t;

    return new(primary)
}




9895114/edit

}
```

Here is the header file

```
extern int linenum;
extern int errcnt;

enum Tokentype {
        T_ERR,
        T_INT,
        T_FLOAT,
        T_PRINT,
        T_SC,
        T_EQUAL,
        T_PLUS,
        T_MINUS,
        T_STAR,
        T_DIV,
        T_MOD,
        T_STARSTAR,
        T_INTCONST,
        T_FLOATCONST,
        T_ID,
        T_LPAREN,
        T_RPAREN,
};

class Token {
        Tokentype       type;
        string          value;
        int             linenum;

public:
        Token(Tokentype t, string v="") {
                type = t;
                value = v;

                linenum = ::linenum;
        }

        Tokentype getType() { return type; }
        string getValue() { return value; }
        int getLinenum() { return linenum; }
};

extern void error(string);
extern int setLexFile(char *);
extern int setLexStdin();
extern Token *getToken();
extern void pushbacktoken( Token * );
```

i want to see if the next thing is not a plus or minus token then push it back and just return what term returned. for example expr() if it IS a plus or minus, use what term returned for the left child and another call to Expr() for the right. I wrote the functions for them, but i am not too sophisticated with them, i added them on top, can someone please let me know if i am heading the right direction or not? and what i should fix?

```
// expr ::= term PLUS expr | term MINUS expr | term
    PTree *
    Expr() {
            Token *t = getToken();
            Tokentype tt = t->getType();
            PTree l = left();
            PTree r = right();
            PTree *term  = Term();

            if(!term){
                    cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
                    return 0;
            }
            else{
                    if(t->getType() != T_PLUS && t->getType() != T_MINUS){
                            return 0;
                    }
                    else{
                            return left();
                    }
            }

            PTree *expr = Expr();
            if(!expr){
                    cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
                    return 0;
            }
            else{
                    if(t->getType() != T_PLUS && t->getType() != T_MINUS){
                            return 0;
            }
            else{
                    return right();
            }
            delete t;
            return new PTree(expr, term);
    }

        // term ::= factor STAR term | factor DIV term | factor MOD term | factor
        PTree *
        Term() {
                Token *t = getToken();
                Tokentype tt = t->getType();
                t = getToken()
                PTree l = left();
                PTree r = right();

                PTree *factor = Factor();
                if(!factor){
                        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
                        return 0;
                }
                else{
                        if(t->getType() != T_STAR && t->getType() != T_DIV && t->getType() != T_MOD){
                                pushbacktoken(t)
                                return 0;
                        }
                        else{
                                return left();
                        }
                }

                PTree *term = Term();
                if (!term){
                        cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
                        return 0;
                }
                else{
                        if(t->getType() != T_STAR && t->getType() != T_DIV && t->getType() !=T_MOD){
                                pushbacktoken(t);
                                return 0;
                        }
                        else{
                                return right();
                        }
                }
                return new PTree(term);
        }

    // factor ::= primary STARSTAR factor | primary
    PTree *
    Factor(){
            Token *t = getToken();
            Tokentype tt = t->getType();
            PTree l = left();
            PTree r = right();

            PTree *primary = Primary();
            if(!primary){
                    cout << "Syntac error on line " << endl;
                    return 0;
            }
            else{
                    if(t->getType() != T_STARSTAR){
                            return 0;
                    }
                    else{
                            return left();
                    }
            }

            PTree *factor = Factor();
            if(!factor){
                    cout << "Syntax error on line " << endl;
                    return 0;
            }
            else{
                    if(t->getType() != T_STARSTAR){
                            return 0;
                    }
                    else{
                            return right();
                    }

            return new PTree(factor, primary);
    }
```

I am getting these errors

```
problem3.cpp: In function ‘PTree* Expr()’:
problem3.cpp:225:17: error: too few arguments to function ‘std::ios_base& std::left(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:918:3: note: declared here
problem3.cpp:226:18: error: too few arguments to function ‘std::ios_base& std::right(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:926:3: note: declared here
problem3.cpp:238:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘std::ios_base& std::left(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:918:3: note: declared here
problem3.cpp:252:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘std::ios_base& std::right(std::ios_base&)’
```

Comment: Aside: Use `:make` inside vim, this will automatically parse the result of make as an error list as GUIs do. You can then use `:cn` and `:cp` to go forwards/backwards. Personally, I add this to my `~/.vimrc`: `:map [ :cn^V^M` (that means, after typing `:cn` press ctrl-v, ctrl-m). Then after doing a :make, you can just press '[' to skip to the next error.

Comment: The problem with tokenType is probably in p3lexer.h but you didn't show that to us.  Can you show us p3lexer.h?

Comment: Where is 'TokenType' declared? The compiler is telling you that it hasn't seen the declaration of TokenType by the time you try and use it.

Comment: google says it's `Tokentype` not `TokenType`

Comment: I just posted up the header file, thanks for the quick responses

Comment: doctorlove nailed it: The header defines "Tokentype", not "TokenType". C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: I have changed TokenType-> Tokentype, still receiving the same errors

Comment: kfsone, i used the make: command in vim that really helped and cut down the errors, i fixed a few of them but still receiving a few others i have no idea mean

Comment: @octain - did you change it in *all* the places? The numbers like 174:8 say the line number:column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variety of errors. Most stem from this:

The header says `Tokentype`, your code says

```
PTree *
Slist() {
    TokenType tt = t->getType();
```

C++ is case sensitive, so you need to change this to

```
PTree *
Slist() {
    Tokentype tt = t->getType();
    //   ^------- lowercase 't'
```

Also another error says

```
‘class Token’ has no member named ‘getToken’
```

It does have a `getType()` function - perhaps you meant to call that instead.

Also, for the error

```
in ‘t->Token::getType != (Tokentype)14u’
```

getType is a function, so you should call it

```
t->Token::getType() != (Tokentype)14u
```

I believe that comes from from tthis line:

```
if(t->getType() != T_STAR && t->getType() != T_DIV && t->getType != T_MOD)
//                                                             ^^^^
```

i.e. change it to

```
if(t->getType() != T_STAR && t->getType() != T_DIV && t->getType() != T_MOD)
//                                                             ^^^^
```

Also, note you have

```
Token *t;
```

inside main, so  the `Slist` function can't see it. You could pass it instead:

```
PTree *
Slist(Token *t) {
```

I suspect as we fix the error you report, you will get more as the compiler gets further. Try to read the messages and fix what you do understand.

Comment: thank you doctorlove, there are some stupid mistakes, i didn't look at them before posting since i was just rushing things, i appreciate the help